# Jquery and Vue, .html() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have been playing with the Vue tutorial [Here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-2-quickstart-tutorial-2017-246195cfbdd2)  and I have added a simple Jquery .html function.  However it is not working.  I have added the jQuery plugin,  and there are no errors in the console.  I have my "App" component defined like this:

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
 <div id="mainMenu"> Hello </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as start from './assets/scripts/start.js'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  created: start.loadMainNavigation()
}
</script>
```

and my loadMainNavigation function like this:

```
function loadMainNavigation() {
    $('#mainMenu').html("ASERFDASRF");
    console.log("In load Nav");
}
```

I can see the "In load Nav"  in the console.  No errors,  but the DIV still has the original "Hello" - What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're really missing out on the benefits of Vue if you do it this way. There's no reason to involve jQuery here.

Comment: You should try document ready. $(document).ready() { $('#mainMenu').html("ASERFDASRF"); }

Answer (score 3):

The reason the content doesn't change is that, at the time you are executing your function, [the component has not yet been rendered to the DOM](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram). The DOM is not rendered until the `mounted` event.

Beyond that, however, you need to be careful when you are integrating jQuery and Vue, or avoid it altogether. The idiomatic Vue way to do this would be something like this.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    message: "Hello"
  },
  created(){
    this.message = "ASERFDASRF"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
   <div id="mainMenu"> {{message}} </div>
 </div>
```

There are a few times when you might mix jQuery and Vue (when you want to use a jQuery plugin for which there is no Vue counterpart, for example) but typically, there is almost always a way to do what you want *without* jQuery.

Comment: So what's the difference between the created:  that I had and the created() {}  that you have?  Aren't they the same thing?  Yes,  yours is a function, and mine calls a function,  but what makes them different when they get called?

Comment: @mmaceachran The primary difference is that the `created` in my example sets a data property. Later, when Vue is rendering the the component, it will use that property display in the DOM. Second, this bit of code `created: start.loadMainNavigation()` sets the `created` handler to *the result of `loadMainNavigation`* which is `undefined`. *If* you changed your code to `mounted: start.loadMainNavigation` your code would probably work because you are setting the handler to an actual function and because at that point in time the DOM would exist.

Comment: @mmaceachran It's perhaps not intuitive that what you have defined in the `template` for your component *does not exist* in the DOM until Vue decides that component should be rendered. The template is converted into a render function that can be used to write to the DOM based on the data contained in the component.

Comment: @mmaceachran [Here](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/yXzPGq?editors=1010). This is not an endorsement of this approach :)